# How to simplify $(x - 1)^n + (x + 1)^n \mod x^2$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Is there any easy way to simplify this?

$$(x - 1)^n + (x + 1)^n \mod x^2$$

Comment: You can expand by binomial theorem. Mod x^2 means you can ignore terms where powers of $x$ is 2 or higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most terms of the binomial expansions of $(x-1)^n$ and $(x+1)^n$ are divisible by $x^2$. The leftover terms are $$((-1)^n+(-1)^{n-1}nx)+(1+nx).$$

If $n$ is even, this equals $2$. If $n$ is odd, this is $2nx$.